# How to fix C++ "Undefined reference to ..." C function pointer?

Tags: c++, c

I am trying to call a function (from an #included library) that takes as a parameter a function pointer, and passing to this function a pointer to a function located in a C file.  The compiler throws an "undefined reference to [function name]" error.

I tried removing the code from the .c file and putting it directly into main.cpp file (see below the section marked 'THIS WORKS') - and the error is avoided.  I know that I should be able to keep it in the .c file because I am following very closely to an example that compiles without errors.

```
/****************/
/*** MAIN.CPP ***/
/****************/

extern "C"
{
    #include "btntask.h"
}

using namespace touchgfx;

/* Kernel includes. */
#include "FreeRTOS.h"
#include "task.h"
#include "queue.h"

#define configGUI_TASK_PRIORITY                 ( tskIDLE_PRIORITY + 3 )
#define configGUI_TASK_STK_SIZE                 ( 1024 )

static void GUITask(void* params)
{
    /* STUFF */
}


/*********** THIS WORKS ************/

/*
void btn_tasked(void* params)/{
    /* STUFF */
}
*/

/*********** THIS WORKS ************/


int main(void)
{
    xTaskCreate(GUITask, "GUITask",
                configGUI_TASK_STK_SIZE,
                NULL,
                configGUI_TASK_PRIORITY,
                NULL);

    /* error undefined reference to btn_task */
    xTaskCreate(btn_task, "BTNTask",
               512,
               NULL,
               configGUI_TASK_PRIORITY+1,
               NULL);

    for (;;);
}
```

This is btntask.h

```
/****************/
/*** btntask.h ***/
/****************/
#ifndef BTNTASK_H
#define BTNTASK_H

    void btn_task(void* params);

#endif /* BTNTASK_H */
```

This is btntask.c

```
/****************/
/*** btntask.c ***/
/****************/

#include "btntask.h"

void btn_task(void* params)
{
  /* STUFF */
}
```

The compiler log is as follows:

```
Converting images
Compiling Core/Src/main.cpp
Linking TouchGFX/build/bin/target.elf
TouchGFX/build/ST/STM32F429IDISCO/Core/Src/main.o: In function `main':
d:\Dropbox\TouchGFXProjects\MiniGame\Project/Core/Src/main.cpp:116: undefined reference to `btn_task'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
gcc/Makefile:363: recipe for target 'TouchGFX/build/bin/target.elf' failed
make[2]: *** [TouchGFX/build/bin/target.elf] Error 1
gcc/Makefile:359: recipe for target 'generate_assets' failed
make[1]: *** [generate_assets] Error 2
../gcc/Makefile:45: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

The compilation is performed by the software package I am using (TouchGFX).  If it is helpful, this is the compilation commands reported in the log:

```
touchgfx update_project --project-file=simulator/msvs/Application.vcxproj && touchgfx update_project --project-file=../EWARM/application.ewp && touchgfx update_project --project-file=../EWARM6/project.ewp && touchgfx update_project --project-file=../MDK-ARM/application.uvproj

make -f ../gcc/Makefile -j8
```

*** UPDATE ***
I noticed that TouchGFX populates a Debug folder of .obj files, one for each of the source code files in the application, and I can see that it is missing a btntask.obj.  Clearly it is not linking the btntask.obj file.  I need to figure out why that is. There is a makefile that details all of the linking, but it uses a lot of syntax I am not familiar with.

*** SOLUTION ***
Turns out that the Makefile names a list of directories to include.  The solution was to edit the list to add additional directories where my btntask files are located.

```
# Directories containing application-specific source and header files.
# Additional components can be added to this list. make will look for
# source files recursively in comp_name/src and setup an include directive
# for comp_name/include.
components := TouchGFX/gui target TouchGFX/generated/gui_generated
```

Thanks everyone for chiming in.

Comment: Are you aware what `extern "C"` does?

Comment: The `extern "C"` looks right, actually, if a bit archaic (normally only seen for C headers from before C++ *existed*). From the output, it looks like the `btntask.c` file simply isn't being compiled or linked in.

Comment: Show the compilation command

Comment: It's difficult to decipher the code that's posted, as it is in all one screens-worth of an edit window.  What was compiled where?  You have an `extern "C"` in one module, then you don't have it for `btntask.c` -- but is this compiled as a C++ or C module? (I don't know how or if the compiler you're using handles the file as a C file or C++ file).  Maybe you should break up your edits, and state exactly what you compiled as one effort, and then what you compiled for your second effort.

Comment: Does TouchGFX know that btntask.c exists? Doesn't looks like it's trying to compile or link it. Some IDEs get pissy if you don't use the IDE to create a file.

Comment: Thanks for the comments.  As an exercise, I tried just calling btn_task from main.c, and it still returns an undefined reference error.  I am thinking that TouchGFX is not aware of btntask.c. Any ideas where / what file identifies the files that are linked?

Comment: Not I, I'm afraid. I've never been exposed to TouchGFX.

Answer (score 1):

You need to be aware these two concepts:

### Name Mangling

You may need to wrap `btn_task` inside `extern "C"` in your `btntask.c` file, as well as in your header file.

As your project contains C++ file, your C file might be compiled by C++ compiler, not C compiler. Then your C function implementation is name-mangled. But the referring position is still using the non-mangled name.

### Link

Don't forget to include product of `btntask.c` in link stage.

After all, I'm not familiar with your project controlling software, you have to ensure those two points by yourself.